# Where can you park a camper or car in Kleve, Goch, Weeze, Kevelaer (North Rhine-Westphalia, Germany)?

Tags: germany, automobiles, camping, campers

I am going to Germany (Kleve, Goch, Weeze, Kevelaer, in North Rhine-Westphalia) in April with my car or camper.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where to park/sleep in the area? Ideally I would like to park for free.

Any ideas would be great!

What are the parking rules in Germany to park a car or camper for 2 or 3 days in neighborhoods in these places? Just in some regular street with houses. Not in the city.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are not many camping sites, but there are some in Germany and some in the Netherlands. I would assume that neither of them have big problems in English, but if you want to make sure, you might want to pick one of these two:

- [camping de hei](http://www.campingdehei.nl/) which is specializing in bikers, they take cars of course too
- [camping klein vink](http://www.tripadvisor.de/Hotel_Review-g652251-d1426097-Reviews-Camping_Klein_Vink-Arcen_Limburg_Province.html) which has a very good TripAdvisor rating

Then there are some in Germany, such as

- [Campingplatz kleve](http://www.sport-reise-animation.de/)
- [Erlengrund](http://www.campingclub-erlengrund.de/)

and one more in the Netherlands:

- [Kasteel Ooijen](http://www.kasteelooijen.nl/)

Of course, all of these are not for free.

Generally, you can park anywhere with a camping car where you could also stop with a normal car and sleep there - just like anyone can sleep in their car to take a rest from driving. What is not legal is to take out a table and chairs etc and have a living-there kind of setup. Also, you might want to change the place of the car after 1 night, since a longer stay might be considered a permanent establishment of sorts and is also not allowed. You also have to watch out for blue parking signs with an additional white sign that might restrict certain cars types from parking there.

Answer (score 5):

> What are the parking rules in Germany to park a car or camper for 2 or 3 days in neighborhoods in these places? Just in some regular street with houses.

As uncovery wrote: officially you're only allowed to spend a single night, and only if it's necessary to restore your fitness as a driver. In a "regular street", you risk complaints.

Ideally, what you're looking for is a [Reisemobil-Stellplatz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reisemobil-Stellplatz) marked by this sign:

[image]
[image]

And now it gets funny: the Wikipedia article has an [example picture](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Stellplatz_Schenkenschanz.JPG) of one such "Stellplatz" - located in Kleve-Schenkenschanz!

But there are many websites that list such sites:

- http://wohnmobil-stellplaetze.net/
- http://www.wohnmobil-atlas.de/
- http://www.mobilisten.de/stellplaetze/deutschland.php